# mobiscroll's setValue doesn't work on subsequent opening of jQM dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-dialog, mobiscroll

A simplified version of my problem is at [github](https://github.com/kanesee/jqm-dialog-mobiscroll).

I'm using mobiscroll 2.6.2 (since that's the last free version on github. Later versions up to 2.11 exists but are on different license).

Basically, I have an index page that does nothing but contains a link to a jQM dialog page.
dialog.html is the jQM dialog page that has a single input, which the mobiscroll library turns into a pop-up scroller for selecting numbers.

The mobiscroll works. The pop-up scroller appears when I select the input. I can select a number from the scroller and it populates the input with my selection. So I'm pretty sure my initialization of mobiscroll is fine. I'll repeat it here for easier review:

```
        $('#mobiInput').mobiscroll()
             .scroller({
                theme: 'ios',
                mode: 'scroller',
                display: 'bubble',
                wheels: [ // Wheel groups array
                  [ // First wheel group
                    {
                      label: 'Number', 
                      values: ['9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1']
                    }
                  ]
                ],
                onSelect: function(valueText, inst) {
                }
            });
```

The function that I'm trying to use is mobiscroll's [setValue function](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/2-11-1/mobiscroll-core)

I set it to the value of "2".

```
var valueArray = ["2"];
$('#mobiInput').mobiscroll('setValue', valueArray, true);
```

This actually works... the first time I open the dialog page. The input shows a value of 2, and when I pop-up the scroller, the value of 2 is selected.

However, when I close the dialog (by clicking cancel button, ok button, or close icon) and reopen the dialog, the setValue function doesn't seem to be working. The value of 2 is not in the input. And when I pop-up the scroller, it defaults to the first value of 9.

My guess is that it's not a bug in mobiscroll, but rather my misunderstanding of jQM ajax navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *Mobiscroll* style sheet and JS library are being loaded each time you open the dialog. Although the *external* dialog is removed from DOM, libraries related to *Mobiscroll* aren't removed.

- **Solution 1:**

  Load all libraries related to *Mobiscroll* as well as *initialization* code in `<head>` of index/first page.

  ```
  <!-- index/first page -->
  <head>
     <!-- Mobiscroll style sheet -->
     <!-- MobiScroll JS library -->
     <script>
        $(document).on("pagecreate", "#dialogID", function () {
           /* initialize Mobiscroll and setValue */
        });
     </script>
  </head>
  ```
- **Solution 2:**

  Load all libraries related to *Mobiscroll* in `<head>` of index/first page. For *initialization* code, place it inside *dialog* div. However, you need to unbind `pagecreate` and bind it again.

  ```
  <!-- index/first page -->
  <head>
     <!-- Mobiscroll style sheet -->
     <!-- MobiScroll JS library -->
  </head>

  <!-- external dialog -->
  <div data-role="page" id="dialogID" data-dialog="true">
     <script>
        $(document).off("pagecreate", "#dialogID").on("pagecreate", "#dialogID", function () {
           /* initialize Mobiscroll and setValue */
        });
     </script>
  </div>
  ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5Lv2E/show/)**

Comment: As always, you're right, Omar! You're like my guardian angel in the jquery-mobile world. lol